add_hparams() function from TensorBoard doesn't work properly
I'm trying to add metrics to this SummaryWriter, but it's not working.
I'm using the add_hparams() function of SummaryWriter, the details of which can be found here: https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensorboard.html.
I'm doing it this way:
writer = SummaryWriter(f'runs/lstm_experiment_final')

for e in tqdm(range(num_epochs)):
    tr_loss, tr_f1, tr_precision, tr_recall = training_loop(model, train_dataloader, loss_function, optimizer, e, writer)
    val_loss, val_f1, val_precision, val_recall = validation_loop(model, test_dataloader, loss_function, e, writer)

metric_dict = {'Loss/train': tr_loss, 'Loss/valid': val_loss,
                         'F1/train': tr_f1, 'F1/valid': val_f1,
                         'Precision/train': tr_precision, 'Precision/valid': val_precision,
                         'Recall/train': tr_recall, 'Recall/valid': val_recall}
writer.add_hparams(best_params, metric_dict, global_step=num_epochs-1)
writer.close()    

This is what's happening.
enter image description here
In other words, hyperparameters are indeed being logged on TensorBoard, but the metric values are not.
I hope someone has already seen my problem and knows how to fix this.
Thanks in advance.
